# How to update for each records without looping in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table and contained data show below, it's called TABLE_A

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
PrimaryID | Col2           | SecondaryID
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1         | Description 1  | 0
2         | Description 2  | 0
3         | Description 3  | 0
4         | Description 4  | 0
.         | ...            | .
.         |
.
```

please see **SecondaryID**, above. its has zero value as an initial value

and I have another table, it's called TABLE_B, below

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
PrimaryID | Col2           | ForeignKeyID
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
1         | Description 1  | 123
2         | Description 2  | 320
3         | Description 3  | 111
4         | Description 4  | 999
.         | ...            | .
.         |
.
```

I have trouble in SQL Server,
How to update **SecondaryID** column on TABLE_A with **ForeignKeyID** value on TABLE_B for each row in TABLE_A's PrimaryID is equal TABLES_B's PrimaryID.
But, I don't want to solve this problem using LOOPING CURSORS or another else.

Are there a simple way??

I need urgent, and thank you in advanced.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. What have you tried? (Did you know that tables can be JOIN'ed in an Update in SQL Server?)

Comment: Well, post what you tried and how it did or didn't work: did it update incorrectly? Not at all? Was there a syntax error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [tsql- update a table using join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/tsql-update-a-table-using-join)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can do a join within an UPDATE operation.  As follows:

```
UPDATE table_a SET SecondaryID = b.ForeignKeyID
FROM table_a a
    JOIN table_b b
    on a.PrimaryID = b.PrimaryID
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fdcdb/6