# Error using Update Join statement from a Table Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

If I make a table variable here:

```
declare @Table Table (ProductID int, Color = varchar(60))
```

Then populate it of course, and try to use it in an `Update` with `Join` statement like below, I get errors.

```
UPDATE [Product]
    SET [Product].[Active] = 1                      
    ,[Product].[Color] = t.[Color]
    INNER JOIN @Table t 
    ON t.[ProductID] = [Product].[ProductID]
```

Error:

```
 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'.
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

Comment: Do you ever read the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you for your answer, it solved my issue.. Too bad you removed it i was about to mark it as best.

Comment: I just discovered this script which I am going to implement. You annoyed the crap out of me this week, and I'm horrible at checking the username before I answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3360/ignore-users-script

Comment: Sorry if i made it harder than usual for you to earn your points.

Comment: I don't give a crap about the points. i care about wasting my time on people who don't value others' time. You need to learn how to ask questions and provide information when asked. Please give this a REALLY GOOD READ: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html and this one too: http://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: PS yes it was me who down-voted this one. Reason: not RTFMing.

Comment: Thank you again Aaron, You never fail to amaze me with your generosity.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for ruining my week.

Comment: What do you mean, it's only Wednesday. :)

Comment: You ruined my week way earlier than today.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also do this (works on SQL Server and all ANSI SQL conforming database):

```
UPDATE [Product] SET 
    [Product].[Active] = 1                      
    ,[Product].[Color] = t.[Color]
FROM @Table t 
WHERE t.[ProductID] = [Product].[ProductID]
```

---

There's something to be desired from SQL Server's proprietary UPDATE FROM though, you can easily change the `UPDATE` statement to make it match whole table regardless if there's no matching rows.

It's easy to fashion this *matched-rows-only* update... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b5a3/26

```
update p SET
  Qty = t.Qty
from Product p
inner join Latest t 
on t.ProductId = p.ProductId;
```

...to an `UPDATE` that matches all rows, you merely change the `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b5a3/27

```
update p SET
  Qty = ISNULL(t.Qty,0)
from Product p
left join Latest t 
on t.ProductId = p.ProductId;


select * from Product;
```

Whereas if you want to fashion the ANSI SQL `UPDATE` with *matched-rows-only* ... http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b5a3/28

```
update Product SET
  Qty = t.Qty
from Latest t
where t.ProductId = Product.ProductId
```

...to `UPDATE` statement that matches all rows, you have to adjust your query a bit: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8b5a3/29

```
update Product SET
  Qty = ISNULL(t.Qty, 0)
from 
(
  select x.ProductId, lat.Qty
  from Product x
  left join Latest lat on lat.ProductId = x.ProductId
) as t  
where t.ProductId = Product.ProductId;
```

Though as most choices in development, one should weigh the pros and cons in terms of code readability/maintainability against flexibility

Data sample:

```
create table Product
(
  ProductId int primary key not null,
  Name varchar(50) not null,
  Qty int not null
  );


insert into Product(Name,Qty) values
(1,'CAR',1),
(2,'Computer',1000),
(3,'Shoes',2);


create table Latest
(
  ProductId int primary key not null,
  Qty int not null
);

insert into Latest(ProductId, Qty) values
(2,2000),
(3,3);
```

Comment: +1. A little cleaner than the proprietary UPDATE...FROM that I always tend to use.