# UPDATE query involving multiple tables

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have two tables..

Persons:

```
  empid(primary key)
  firstname
  lastname
  email
```

Details:

```
  Did(primary key)
  salary
  designation
  empid
```

Now I need to UPDATE email of the employee whose name is 'abc' AND designation is Manager.(lets suppose there are more than one employees names abc and therefore designation needs to be checked)
I am using sql server 2008

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE p
  SET email = 'newemail@wherever.com'
  FROM dbo.Persons AS p
  INNER JOIN dbo.Details AS d
  ON p.empid = d.empid
  WHERE p.firstname = 'abc'
  AND d.Designation = 'manager';
```

Comment: I had no idea you could use an alias like that.  It's always seemed strange to me that you need to specify the table twice.  I come from Access where an update statement never has a `FROM` clause; you simply do `UPDATE Persons INNER JOIN Detail ON Persons.PersonID = Detail.PersonID SET email = 'us@them.com'`

Comment: SQL Server syntax is different in a LOT of ways from Access.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
UPDATE 
  [Persons] 
SET 
  [Persons].[email]='###@###.###'
FROM 
  [Persons] 
  INNER JOIN [Persons].[empid] 
  ON [Details].[empid] = [Persons].[empid] 
WHERE 
  [Persons].[firstname]='abc' AND 
  [Details].[designation]='Manager'
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN [Persons].[empid]`? Aside from the error and not using table aliases, how is this different from my answer?

Comment: @AaronBertrand at least he changed the formatting, the email string, and capitalized 'Manager'