# Update with inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-update

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

I am stuck on a very simple query, an update with a join, I want to put the value of the field RECORDTYPE in the RECORDTYPE field = to the value of TEMPLATETABLE.RECORDTYPE

I tried with this but I get continuous syntax errors, which is the problem?

```
update MAINTABLE MT
set MT.MYTYPE =  TT.RECORDTYPE 
inner join TEMPLATETABLE TT on TT.ID_RECORD_TEMPLATE = MT.ID_RECORD_TEMPLATE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `FROM` clause. Try this instead:

```
UPDATE MT
SET MT.MYTYPE =  TT.RECORDTYPE 
FROM MAINTABLE MT
INNER JOIN TEMPLATETABLE TT 
        ON TT.ID_RECORD_TEMPLATE = MT.ID_RECORD_TEMPLATE
```