# Update database from another using joins?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to update a table from another database using joins and having a hard time. This is what I am trying to do in pseudo:

```
UPDATE [Database1].[dbo].[Sessions]
   SET [SpeakerID] = ?STATEMENT1?
 WHERE ?STATEMENT2?
```

For "Statement1", this would be coming from another database and table that has columns: SessionID and SpeakerID. How can this be achieved?

Comment: please post the structure of two tables and how are they related with each other (*linking columns*)

Comment: how should the tables be joined?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE  a
SET     a.SpeakerID = b.colName          -- SET valoue here
FROM    Database1.dbo.Sessions a
        INNER JOIN Database2.dbo.Sessions b
            ON a.SessionID = b.SessionID -- assumes that their 
                                         -- relationship column is SessionID, 
                                         -- change it in your original columnName
WHERE   ....
```

`a` and `b` are called alias. They are useful when you have longer source name.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE L
  SET SpeakerID = R.SpeakerID
  FROM dbo.LocalTable AS L
  INNER JOIN RemoteDatabase.dbo.RemoteTable AS R
  ON L.SomeValue = R.SomeValue;
```

This really is no different from [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212) except you have to add a database prefix to one of the tables in the join.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UPDATE [Database1].[dbo].[Sessions]
SET
    Sessions.col1 = other_table.col1
FROM
    [Database1].[dbo].[Sessions] Sessions
INNER JOIN
    [Database2].[dbo].other_table AS other_table
ON
    Sessions.id = other_table.id
WHERE Sessions.id = ??
```

Note if the database is on another server you will need to create a linked server first

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx