# SQL Insert statement for multiple values

Tags: sql, insert, multiple-columns

I am little confused whether we can accomplish inserting multiple rows / multiple values for few same values. To make it less complicated my table should look as shown below. Right now i have data in excel.

[image]

I would like to insert SET_VALUE by keeping other row values being the same. The only other option i can think of is inserting multiple times :(

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME
  VALUES ( null, 100, 'miscellaneous', 'book', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );
```

Comment: Where do you read your data from?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/452859/inserting-multiple-rows-in-a-single-sql-query

Comment: Do you want to change the current values or actually create new rows?

Comment: i have data from excel which i need to insert into table, actually insert new rows.

Comment: if the data's small enough, you can use the clipboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into inserting with a `SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAMES (col1, col2, changingCol, col4)
SELECT
    ConstantValue1,
    ConstantValue2,
    MyChangingValue,
    ConstantValue4
FROM
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [OPENROWSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx) command. [More examples to show some of the flexibility with the OPENROWSET command](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1540/insert-update-or-delete-data-in-sql-server-from-excel/)

let's assume that an ID IDENTITY

```
INSERT TABLE_NAME(SET_ID, SET_NAME, SET_VALUE, LOGIN_TIME)
SELECT 100, 'miscellaneous', SET_VALUE, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
                'Excel 8.0;Database = C:\OPENROWSET_Examples.xls;', 
                'SELECT SET_VALUE FROM [INSERT_Example$]') 
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212)

> QUOTE

```
UPDATE a
  SET a.CalculatedColumn = b.[Calculated Column]
  FROM Table1 AS a
  INNER JOIN Table2 AS b
  ON a.CommonField = b.[Common Field]
  WHERE a.BatchNo = '110';
```

Comment: I would like to insert SET_VALUE by keeping other row values being the same   ------ I think he wants an update

Comment: On one of his comments, he says "i have data from excel which i need to insert into table, actually insert new rows". So he wants to insert them.

Comment: so he is having dynamic requirements :-)