# Update from Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-update, temp-tables

Query:

```
SELECT ID, T.c.value('@Address', 'nvarchar(20)' ) as Address
INTO #TMP
FROM TABLE1
    CROSS APPLY XMLData.nodes('/Document') AS T(c)

UPDATE TABLE1
SET HomeAddress = (SELECT TOP 1 t.Address
                   FROM #TMP t
                   WHERE t.ID = ID)
```

Mainly, I need to copy data OUT from an XML field to normal fields within the same table.

Questions:

1. Any reason why all the records get the HomeAddress on Table1?
2. Is really Cursor the only way to update the value on Table1?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 25):

```
UPDATE T2
SET HomeAddress = t1.address
FROM TABLE2 t2
join TABLE1 t1 on T1.ID = t2.HomeAddressID
and t2.HomeAddress <> t1.address
```

Use a join. No need to temp table or correlated subquery.

If table 1 is in a one to many relationshisp these are some posibilites for handling that. If you havea value that indicates one and only one record (we have a field in our system that picks the most important address, it is maintained with a trigger to guarantee uniquesness), the try this:

```
UPDATE T2
SET HomeAddress = t1.address
FROM TABLE2 t2
join TABLE1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.HomeAddressID
WHERE t1.somefield = 'somevalue'
and t2.HomeAddress <> t1.address
```

If you need to based the unique record on asome other field (such as the most recent date), then try a variation of this:

```
UPDATE T2
SET HomeAddress = t1.address
FROM TABLE2 t2
join TABLE1 t1 on t1.ID = t2.HomeAddressID
join (select id, max(somedatefield) from  table1 group by id) t3 on t3.id = t1.id
Where  t2.HomeAddress <> t1.address
```

Comment: If t1.id has a one to many relationship with t2.homeaddressid, you might need to be a bit more specific on what record to use.

Comment: the real values are inside an XML field. I just updated the original question.

Comment: @DanBracuk, excellent point. Of course the current version isn't specifying which to use either in that case. Let me cobble up some examples though.

Answer (score 4):

On the update, I need to FULLY QUALIFY the Table as follow:

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET TABLE1.HomeAddress = (SELECT TOP 1 t.Address  
               FROM #TMP t  
               WHERE t.ID = TABLE1.ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT P.TipoComprob,P.NoComprob,C.Importe as ImpIVA1,ROUND(100/P.ImpGravado*C.Importe,1)
 as PorcIVA1 
       INTO #Temporal
       FROM ComprobProv AS P
       LEFT JOIN PasesCompras AS C ON C.TipoComprob=P.TipoAsiento AND 
C.NoComprob=P.NoComprob
WHERE P.PorcIVA1 =0 and P.CatIVA = 'Ri' AND P.ImpGravado>0 AND C.CodCuenta=110303010 AND ROUND(100/P.ImpGravado*C.Importe,1) IN (21.00,10.50,27.00);
go

select * from #Temporal;
go

UPDATE 
   t1 
SET 
   t1.ImpIVA1 =  t2.ImpIVA1, t1.PorcIVA1 = t2.PorcIVA1
FROM
   dbo.ComprobProv t1
   INNER JOIN #Temporal t2
   ON t1.TipoComprob = t2.TipoComprob AND t1.NoComprob = t2.NoComprob;
go
```

-- Note that the 'GO' are important to preserve the context in SQL Server 2017, otherwise you'll find an 
'unknown field name' error.