# copy column value from one database.table to another database.table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Let's keep it short and sweet

I want to do this (I've failed numerous times now, and one attempt even updated the Row with blanks):

```
UPDATE Database2.Table1 
SET (Database2.Table1.Column1, Database2.Table1.Column2, Database2.Table1.Column3) 
VALUES 
   (Database1.Table1.Column1, Database1.Table1.Column2, Database1.Table1.Column3)
WHERE Database2.Table1.Column1 = Database1.Table1.Column1
```

These two already contain the same value, but the other 2 columns do not, and that is what I wish to change with this query..

Here's how each table look:

**Database1.Table1**

```
[id]
[name]
[applicationdate]
[startdate]
[shortdescription]
[longdescription]
[displayimg]
[contact]
[website]
[created]
[urlbase]
[site]
[keywords]
[type]
[location]
```

**Database2.Table1**

```
[id]
[name]
[applicationdate]
[startdate]
[content]
[keywords]
[customerid]
[urlbase]
[shortdescription]
[meta]
[type]
[site]
[searchurlbase]
[lang]
[educationlength]
[locations]
[educationwebsite]
[contact]
[tags]
[educationtypes]
[created]
[category]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you for your time :)

Sorry if it doesn't make any sense, I easily get confused when trying to explain problems I'm having

Comment: Are those two databases on the same server instance? Or if not: is there a "linked server" connection between the two servers?

Comment: yes they are on the same server instance @marc_s

Comment: Values is used by an insert statement.  An update is set colX = colY

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
UPDATE dest
  SET column2 = src.column2,
      column3 = src.column3
FROM Database2.dbo.Table1 AS dest 
INNER JOIN Database1.dbo.Table1 AS src
ON dest.column1 = src.column1;
```

Given your collate problem, you can specify collate in the equality operation. Having no idea which side is giving the problem, and assuming you don't care about case sensitivity:

```
UPDATE dest
  SET column2 = src.column2,
      column3 = src.column3
FROM Database2.dbo.Table1 AS dest 
INNER JOIN Database1.dbo.Table1 AS src
ON dest.column1 COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS
 = src.column1  COLLATE Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS;
```

If you care about case sensitivity, then change both clauses to the `_CS_AS_` one.

Comment: Thank you very much, got a collate issue going on now though, you wouldnt happen to know what to do when it throws this error at you 'Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Finnish_Swedish_CS_AS_KS_WS" and "Finnish_Swedish_CI_AS" in the equal to operation."

Answer (score -1):

It is too easy in mysql, if your databases in same server.
The mysql command is:
**insert into db2.table_name(column_name you want) select from table1_name.coumn_name you want from table1**

For example,
                  insert into db2.new(id,name,email) select from register.id,register.name,register.email from register.

Where, db2 is 2nd db
       new is table in db2
       register is in db1 where you copy data from this db to db