# Django migrate ImageFiles from one app to another

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have two django apps on heroku, `app_B` is a copy of a section of `app_A`.
 
The `app_A` has models with `ImageField`:

```
image = models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=get_image_uri)
```

I'd like to copy these objects to the `app_B`.
The model I'd like to copy looks exactly the same. The images are stored in Amazon AWS.

The django command `dumpdata` / `loaddata` gives me FK errors.. 
However, I could try to solve those FK errors but I'm not sure if `loaddata` can copy the images themselves, or am I missing something? 
Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks like with your rep here, you know that asking such a broad question is off-topic. A question requires code, and a question specific to a problem related to it.

Comment: Ok, I'll add some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can perform a [raw SQL query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries):

```
ModelB.objects.raw(
    '''
    INSERT INTO appb_modelb (image)
    SELECT image FROM appa_modela
    '''
)
```

The above assumes that your tables are in the same database and your `appb_modelb` table is empty at the moment of the copy.

The are more complicated SQL queries that you can achieve this way, should the need rises, like [copy a column to a table from a different database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16017660/copy-column-value-from-one-database-table-to-another-database-table?answertab=votes#tab-top).

You must be careful though. Read [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries) carefully and especially the warnings in there!

Good luck :)