# Creating a Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a stored procedure that will allow me to update the ActualArrivalDate and ActualDepartureDate in a TripStop table where StopTypeCode = Drop in the TripStopOrder table.

```
Create Proc spUpdateTable
@OrderID int, @ArrivalDate datetime, @DepartureDate datetime

As

Begin 

   Begin Transaction
   Select * From dbo.TripStopOrder
   Join dbo.TripStop ON dbo.TripStopOrder.TripStopID = dbo.TripStop.TripStopID
   Where OrderID = ''and StopTypeCode ='Drop'
```

Once I find this record I need to grab the TripStopId and pass it into the Update statement.
Not sure how to this...can I use a temp table then run another Select statement to pick up the TripStopID?

```
   Update dbo.TripStop SET ArrivalDate='',DepartureDate=''
   Where TripStopID = ''

End
Commit
```

Any ideas or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. ~Newbie~

Comment: store the TripStopId in a temp variable and then use it in update e.g.  select @v_tripstopid = tripstopid From dbo.TripStopOrder
     Join dbo.TripStop ON dbo.TripStopOrder.TripStopID = dbo.TripStop.TripStopID
     Where OrderID = ''and StopTypeCode ='Drop'  and then in update use Update dbo.TripStop SET ArrivalDate='',DepartureDate=''
Where TripStopID = #v_tripstopid

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing the SELECT and then the UPDATE, just change your WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement:

```
WHERE TripStopID = (SELECT T.TripStopID FROM TripStopOrder O
INNER JOIN TripStop T ON O.TripStopID = T.TripStopID
WHERE OrderID = @OrderID AND StopTypeCode = 'Drop')
```

Comment: Thank you.  This does exactly what I need it to do.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign the value to a variable such as `@TripStopId`:

```
DECLARE @TripStopId INT

Select @TripStopid = TripStopId
From dbo.TripStopOrder
Join dbo.TripStop ON dbo.TripStopOrder.TripStopID = dbo.TripStop.TripStopID
Where OrderID = ''and StopTypeCode ='Drop'
```

Then you can use it in your `UPDATE` statement.

```
Update dbo.TripStop SET ArrivalDate='',DepartureDate=''
Where TripStopID = @TripStopId
```

Comment: Thank you.  That's much simpler than what I was trying to do.