# I have to update one table field as another field of different table in sql

Tags: asp-classic

I have to update one table field as another field of different table in sql. There are two tables, create_account and Trans_Details. I have to update amount field of create_account table and set it into current_balance of Trans_Details table. How can I join these two tables? please write a query for this.

Comment: [this ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the sub queries to do this...

Example:

I do not know what kind of data base r u using i am just giving a pseudo code..

```
UPDATE  create_account SET (amount) = ( SELECT current_balance FROM Trans_Details
         WHERE filter = some_value) WHERE filter = some_value.
```

I have added the where clause in the query, please ignore if u want to update the entire row in the column amount.

Comment: UPDATE create_account1
SET create_account1.amount = Trans_Details.Current_Balance
FROM create_account1 
INNER JOIN Trans_Details ON create_account1.maccountno = Trans_Details.DAccNo . Is it correct?