# SQL Update values in table A with multiple values from table B

Tags: sql, matching

I'm trying to update products' prices in table A with prices from table B based on their product code.

There are about 50,000 products in table A but only 200 in table B.
So I want those 200 prices in table B to replace the prices of those products in table A by matching the product code in both tables.

Can anyone advise me on how to go about doing it?

Comment: Which is your database? Sql server, oracle, MySql etc.

Comment: Have you tried something to do?

Comment: My database is on sql server. 
I tried to get some references from sites and edited my sql statement to be this.

UPDATE dbo.Shelflabel_Pricechange_Master
SET [Unit Price] = (SELECT t2.[Unit Price] FROM dbo.shelflabel_pricechange t2 WHERE dbo.Shelflabel_Pricechange_Master.Plu = t2.PLU)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM dbo.shelflabel_pricechange t2
     WHERE dbo.Shelflabel_Pricechange_Master.Plu = t2.PLU)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE  TableA
SET     TableA.ProductPrice= TableB.price
FROM    TableA
INNER JOIN  TableB
ON  TableA.productCode = TableB.productCode
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner join update for MS Sql server(reference: [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)). Please try below query:

```
UPDATE 
 TableA
SET TableA.Price = TableB.Price
FROM 
 TableA, TableB
WHERE 
 TableA.ProductCode = TableB.ProductCode
```

Comment: Isn't it preferable to use explicit join syntax rather than the old FROM Table,Table. Only reason i upvoted @Nadeem_MK answer.

Answer (score 0):

## try this command in mysql

```
update A t
set cost=(select cost from B where id=t.id)
where t.id in (select id from B)
```