# SQL Server Update trigger not working properly on batch update

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, triggers

I have the following simple trigger for row update. What it is supposed to do is to update the LastUpdatedDate column on the rows that are updated. It works well with single row update but not the batch row update that is fired up from the application side.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [gc].[T_UpdateObservation] ON [gc].[GCUR_OBSERVATION] 
  AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- get the last id value of the record inserted or updated
    DECLARE @id INT
    SELECT @id = [ObservationId]
    FROM DELETED

    -- Update statements for trigger here
    UPDATE GCUR_OBSERVATION
    SET GCUR_OBSERVATION.LastUpdatedDate = getdate()
    WHERE [ObservationId] = @id

END
```

Could anyone give some tips? Thanks in advance!

Cheers,
Alex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to build a [set-based updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212) instead of one based on a single variable:

```
ALTER TRIGGER [gc].[T_UpdateObservation] 
ON [gc].[GCUR_OBSERVATION] 
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE g SET LastUpdatedDate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    FROM gc.GCUR_OBSERVATION AS g
    -----^^ why is the schema missing from your version of the trigger?
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i
    ON g.ObservationID = i.ObservationID;
END
GO
```