# The multi-part identifier could not be bound error

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to copy the values of one column (reg_id) in members_profile to the empty (reg_id)
column in reg_members. 
On executing this query i am getting the multi-part identifier could not be bound error.

```
INSERT INTO testing.db1.members_profile(reg_id) 
SELECT reg_id 
from testing.db1.reg_members 
WHERE testing.db1.members_profile.loginname = testing.db1.reg_members.loginname;
```

Comment: What is `testing`? A linked server? A database? If that's supposed to be a four-part name, it's missing the schema (e.g. `dbo`) between `db1` and the table name. And I don't understand - you're trying to insert a new row or update an existing row that matches between the two tables?

Comment: @AaronBertrand testing is the name of my database. I am trying to copy all values of reg_id column in members_profile table to an empty column in reg_members.

Comment: And so you have a schema named `db1`? If so, that's a very confusing schema name.

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes :-|

Comment: You should think about fixing that, because it's quite misleading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to update an existing row (or rows), you should be writing an `UPDATE` statement, not an `INSERT`. An `INSERT` adds rows, an `UPDATE` updates them.

I believe what you're looking for is an [`UPDATE` based on a `JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212) (and you should use table aliases so that you don't have to repeat `database.table.column` on every single reference and clause):

```
UPDATE r
  SET r.reg_id = m.reg_id
  FROM testing.db1.members_profile AS m
  INNER JOIN testing.db1.reg_members AS r
  ON m.loginname = r.loginname;
```