# Porting a query with respect to SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, migrate, vectorwise

I have a query in Vectorwise DB as,

```
UPDATE current_load_details cld
 FROM date_dim dd
SET current_date_sk = dd.date_sk
,batchstring = date_part('YEAR', dd.dateval) || CASE 
     WHEN length(date_part('MONTH', dd.dateval)) = 1
         THEN '0' || date_part('MONTH', dd.dateval)
     ELSE date_part('MONTH', dd.dateval)
     END || CASE 
    WHEN length(date_part('DAY', dd.dateval)) = 1
        THEN '0' || date_part('DAY', dd.dateval)
     ELSE date_part('DAY', dd.dateval)
     END

     ,is_last_run_successful = 0
          WHERE cld.load_date = dd.dateval
```

I need to migrate it to SQLSERVER,
I have tried this,

```
UPDATE cld.current_load_details 
 FROM dd1.date_dim 
SET current_date_sk = dd1.date_sk
,batchstring = datepart(yyyy, dd1.dateval) OR CASE 
    WHEN length(datepart(mm, dd1.dateval)) = 1
        THEN '0' OR datepart(mm, dd.dateval)
    ELSE datepart(mm, dd1.dateval)
    END OR CASE 
    WHEN length(datepart(dd, dd1.dateval)) = 1
        THEN '0' OR datepart(dd1, dd.dateval)
    ELSE datepart(dd, dd1.dateval)
    END

,is_last_run_successful = 0
     WHERE cld.load_date = dd1.dateval
```

It still gives error.Please help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `||` is being uses to concatenate (rather than logical OR) the date into `yyyymmdd` format which in T-SQL can be done with a conversion:

```
 convert(varchar(8), dd1.dateval, 112)
```

Giving

```
UPDATE 
    cld.current_load_details 
SET 
    current_date_sk = dd1.date_sk,
    batchstring =  convert(varchar(8), dd1.dateval, 112),
    is_last_run_successful = 0
FROM 
    dd1.date_dim
    ??? 
WHERE cld.load_date = dd1.dateval
```

??? is where you presumably want to [define a JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server).

Comment: it seems like "WHERE cld.load_date = dd.dateval" is the JOIN condition in vectorwise query. so OP will not need any additional join.