# UPDATE table via join in SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-update, join

I am trying to normalize my tables to make the db more efficient.

To do this I have removed several columns from a table that I was updating several columns on.

Here is the original query when all the columns were in the table:

```
UPDATE myActDataBaselDataTable 
set [Correct Arrears 2]=(case when [Maturity Date]='' then 0 else datediff(d,convert(datetime,@DataDate, 102),convert(datetime,[Maturity Date],102)) end)
from myActDataBaselDataTable
```

Now I have removed `[Maturity Date]` from the table **myActDataBaselDataTable** and it's necessary to retrieve that column from the base reference table `ACTData`, where it is called `Mat`.

In my table **myActDataBaselDataTable** the Account number field is a concatenation of 3 fields in **ACTData**, thus

```
myActDataBaselDataTable.[Account No]=ac.[Unit] + ' ' + ac.[ACNo] + ' ' + ac.[Suffix]
```

(where ac is the alias for **ACTData**)

So, having looked at the answers given elsewhere on SO (such as [1604091: update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)), I tried to modify this particular update statement as below, but I cannot get it right:

```
UPDATE myActDataBaselDataTable 
set dt.[Correct Arrears 2]=(
    case when ac.[Mat]='' 
        then 0 
        else datediff(d,convert(datetime,'2014-04-30', 102),convert(datetime,ac.[Mat],102))
    end)
from ACTData ac 
inner join myActDataBaselDataTable  dt
    ON dt.[Account No]=ac.[Unit] + ' ' + ac.[ACNo] + ' ' + ac.[Suffix]
```

I either get an `Incorrect syntax near 'From'` error, or `The multi-part identifier "dt.Correct Arrears 2" could not be bound.`

I'd be grateful for any guidance on how to get this right, or suugestiopns about how to do it better.

thanks

**EDIT:**

BTW, when I run the below as a *SELECT* it returns data with no errors:

```
select case when [ac].[Mat]='' 
            then 0 
                else datediff(d,convert(datetime,'2014-04-30', 102),convert(datetime,[ac].[Mat],102))
        end
        from ACTData ac 
    inner join myActDataBaselDataTable  dt
        ON dt.[Account No]=ac.[Unit] + ' ' + ac.[ACNo] + ' ' + ac.[Suffix]
```

Comment: Try update dt rather than update myActDataBaselDataTable

Comment: thanks for that (very simple, but eluded me totally!), perhaps you could expand on it into answer that I could choose to help the next person who finds it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a join update, update the alias

```
update dt
```

What is confusing is that in later versions of SQL you don't need to use the alias in the update line