# SQL Server ambigous col name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

this is concerning SQL Server Management

I have been getting this error when trying to update a table: "Ambiguous column name 'Id'."

this is the query:

```
update DispatcherDB.dbo.Engineer
set MobilePhone = RestoreDB.dbo.W6ENGINEERS.MobilePhone
from DispatcherDB.dbo.Engineer join RestoreDB.dbo.W6ENGINEERS
on Id = W6Key
```

I have done this query before on other tables without a problem. I'm still a novice when it come to SQL, so any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: You need to tell the ON clause which Id column you mean (there is obviously one in both tables - and what a horrible name for a column anyway). Also please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212).

Comment: You have the `id` field in the tables you use in this update, you need to add either an alias or table name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give aliases to your tables (not really have to, but nice to do) and then you have to define of which table the id you are using in the on clause.

```
update E
set MobilePhone = W.MobilePhone
from DispatcherDB.dbo.Engineer E join RestoreDB.dbo.W6ENGINEERS W
on E.Id = W.W6Key
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `UPDATE E` not `UPDATE Dispatcher...`? You can also use the W alias in the second line...

Comment: The whole point of using an alias though is to not have to repeat `database.schema.table` throughout the query. I like the answer (+1) it just seems like it's arguing with itself: "Aliases are good!" "But I don't want to use an alias!"

Comment: @AaronBertrand I would have say "Yes, this is why i use it in the on clause", but that would have sounded silly as i do not use it in the update!!! :-)

Comment: I can scream on the internet too!

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the edit...i totally missed that, as it was mostly a copy and paste from the question's code.

Comment: Well I did mention it in my first comment. :-)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Indeed, but i edited only the `Update DispatcherDB.dbo.Engineer`.