# Aliased tables and updates... shouldn't this code fail?

Tags: sql-server

Once a table is aliased, it needs to be referred to by the alias, right?

This will fail...

> Use AdventureWorks;
>
> SELECT TOP 10 Store.Name
> FROM Store as st

...But this update would not.

> Use AdventureWorks;
>
> UPDATE Store
> SET Name = Name + '$Test'
>
> FROM Store as st

Does SQL Server parse any action verbs before it begins it's order of precedence of select operations?

Comment: Why do you have a FROM clause? You've already referenced the table you want to update - it's in the UPDATE clause. If you're trying to update based on a join, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1604091/61305) - that's the only scenario where I think you'd need to reference the table with an optional FROM.

Answer (score 4):

In

```
UPDATE Store
SET Name = Name + '$Test'
FROM Store as st
```

you are referencing *two* tables. You are referencing `Store` two times.

```
UPDATE Store
SET Name = Name + '$Test'
FROM sys.objects as st
```

would work just as well. This is a cross-product of two tables that is being updated.

In general, the alias rule applies to DML as well.

Comment: huh I am confused. Why am I referencing two tables? I thought I was updating Store in adventure works. you lost me with system objects. The code above isn't referencing any system tables.

Comment: Look at it this way, you can write `UPDATE Store SET Name = Name + "Test"`, so when you add in the extra alias in the FROM clause, it's adding the table to your query again, hence the cross-product.

Comment: Try it out. Put sys.objects into your query. It still runs. You'll find a small difference in the query plan. Just the fact that you used the same table name two times does not mean that you reference one table. It just looks like it.

Comment: If that's the case, why am I able to use the alias in the update statement instead of the table name and get the same result? How can I be referencing two tables then?

Comment: When you use the alias you are referring to the table that has this alias. If you say UPDATE st then there is no longer a cross product because you no longer introduce another table in the UPDATE clause. The cross product only manifests itself here if st has zero rows. In that case nothing will be updated.

Comment: What does `UPDATE T1 SET ... FROM T2` do, in your mind? This is a valid statement.