# Update a table with JOIN - MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to update a column with a calculated column in a inner join.
The logic is simple but I am struggling with the syntax
(this is just a dummy SQL, to explain what I am trying to accomplish - it does not run)

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.BodyText = t2.final
from Questions as t1 
INNER JOIN translations as t2 
on t2.QuestionId=t1.QuestionID
CONCAT(t1.BodyText,t2.QuestionBodyText) as final
```

The task is simple, concat a question with its translation. I found some questions related to this issue on stackoverflow, but they where no help, maybe because they were discussing SQL Server.

Similar:
[Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

I tried that:

```
UPDATE Questions t1
JOIN translations t2
on t1.QuestionID=t2.QuestionId
SET t1.BodyText = CONCAT(t1.BodyText,t2.QuestionBodyText)
```

But it does not have any effect on the database.

This is an equivalent SELECT that works:

```
SELECT CONCAT(t1.BodyText,t2.QuestionBodyText)  FROM Questions t1
JOIN translations t2
on t1.QuestionID=t2.QuestionId
```

Update, when I used this update query on phpmyadmin it worked, on workbench it did not..

Comment: I don't think this sql runs. Subqueries must be aliased. t2.final refers to nothing, since t2 is declared in your subquery (`select Questions as t1...`)

Comment: it does not run, I just put as an example to see what I am trying to do.

Comment: `Set t1.BodyText = CONCAT(t1.BodyText,t2.QuestionBodyText)`, and get rid of the last line of your query.

Comment: I have tried that, but it highlights the word "from" as an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, your syntax is out of whack.

```
Update Questions t1
join translations t2
on t2.QuestionID = t1.QuestionID
set t1.BodyText = concat(t1.bodytext,t2.questionbodytext)
```

Comment: Thanks. I corrected on the way you said, but it runs without any changes. I will investigate more, it might be another problem.

Comment: no changes. which is weird because if I convert this query into a select it works as expected.

Comment: Update, when I used this query on phpmyadmin it worked, on workbench it did not..

Comment: SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;  you have to run that before you run the update in mysql workbench