# SQL UPDATE using two joined subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, subquery, inner-join

I wrote a query that does an inner join of two subqueries.  The first subquery has an alias of "SRC" and the other has an alias of "DEST".  What I want to do is update some fields in the table NomineeActionLegislatorVoteDetail (part of DEST subquery) with values from the table Nominee_Committee_Vote (part of SRC subquery).  It souds easy but I just cannot figure out how to do it.  Does anyone have any suggestions?  Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the query I wrote:

```
select * 
from (
    select  ncv.*,
        na.NomineeActionId,
        l.LegislatorId
    from ongoing..Nominee_Committee_Vote ncv
    inner join azleg..NomineeAction na on
        ncv.session_id    = na.x_session_id   and
        ncv.committee_id  = na.x_committee_id and
        ncv.agency_id     = na.x_agency_id    and
        ncv.position_id   = na.x_position_id  and
        ncv.nominee_id    = na.x_nominee_id   and
        ncv.received_date = na.x_received_date
    inner join status..session s on
        ncv.session_id    = s.session_id
    inner join azleg..Legislator l on
        ncv.member_id     = l.x_member_id     and
        s.legislature     = l.LegislatureId
) SRC
inner join (
    select votedetail.*
    from azleg..NomineeActionLegislatorVoteDetail votedetail
    inner join azleg..NomineeAction nom_action on
        votedetail.NomineeActionId = nom_action.NomineeActionId
) DEST on
    SRC.agency_id     = DEST.x_agency_id     and
    SRC.position_id   = DEST.x_position_id   and
    SRC.nominee_id    = DEST.x_nominee_id    and
    SRC.received_date = DEST.x_received_date and
    SRC.session_id    = DEST.x_session_id    and
    SRC.committee_id  = DEST.x_committee_id  and
    SRC.member_id     = DEST.x_member_id
where   SRC.NomineeActionId <> DEST.NomineeActionId
   OR   SRC.LegislatorId <> DEST.LegislatorId
   OR   SRC.Vote <> DEST.Vote
```

Comment: The question is unclear to me. What table do you need to update?

Comment: UPDATE TABLENAME
SET Column = Sub.Field
FROM TABLENAME
JOIN (SUBQUERY) AS Sub ON TABLENAME.ID = Sub.ID

Comment: You need to include which of the two tables you want to update. You should also indicate which fields you want to update and with which values. Also Inequality as a joining condition will likely cause problems with an update if more than one value in source satisfies the join condition. How will you pick the correct row?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: I have revised the question.  It is different from other questions because because I am dealing with two subqueries (SRC and DEST)

Comment: No, it's really still the same as the link @TabAlleman posted.  Two derived tables (sub-queries) is really no different than two actual tables.

Answer (score 0):

Can you insert the update in front of the sub queries

```
UPDATE NomineeActionLegislatorVoteDetail 
SET NomineeActionLegislatorVoteDetail.COLUMNNAME = src.VALUE
--SubQueriesBelow
from
(select ncv.*, na.NomineeActionId, l.LegislatorId from ongoing..Nominee_Committee_Vote ncv
inner join azleg..NomineeAction na on
ncv.session_id = na.x_session_id and
ncv.committee_id = na.x_committee_id and
ncv.agency_id = na.x_agency_id and
ncv.position_id = na.x_position_id and
ncv.nominee_id = na.x_nominee_id and
ncv.received_date = na.x_received_date
inner join status..session s on
ncv.session_id = s.session_id
inner join azleg..Legislator l on
ncv.member_id = l.x_member_id and
s.legislature = l.LegislatureId) SRC
inner join
(select votedetail.* from azleg..NomineeActionLegislatorVoteDetail votedetail
inner join azleg..NomineeAction nom_action on
votedetail.NomineeActionId = nom_action.NomineeActionId) DEST on
SRC.agency_id = DEST.x_agency_id and
SRC.position_id = DEST.x_position_id and
SRC.nominee_id = DEST.x_nominee_id and
SRC.received_date = DEST.x_received_date and
SRC.session_id = DEST.x_session_id and
SRC.committee_id = DEST.x_committee_id and
SRC.member_id = DEST.x_member_id
where SRC.NomineeActionId <> DEST.NomineeActionId
OR SRC.LegislatorId <> DEST.LegislatorId
OR SRC.Vote <> DEST.Vote
```

It looks like the update is on a table in the sub query so it could be re factored to have one subquery

Answer (score 0):

I've adjusted the lay-out of your query a bit to disclose better where subqueries start and end. In your `DEST` subquery, you `join NomineeAction` but you don't select any columns from it, so it only *filters* rows from `NomineeActionLegislatorVoteDetail` for which no `NomineeAction` exists. So really you wanna be updating and joining on columns from `NomineeActionLegislatorVoteDetail` exclusively. Based on that, I would write the `update` query like so:

```
update votedetail set
    votedetail.SomeColumn = SomeValue,
    votedetail.SomeOtherColumn = SomeOtherValue
from azleg..NomineeActionLegislatorVoteDetail votedetail
join azleg..NomineeAction nom_action on
        votedetail.NomineeActionId = nom_action.NomineeActionId
join (
    select  ncv.*,
        na.NomineeActionId,
        l.LegislatorId
    from ongoing..Nominee_Committee_Vote ncv
    inner join azleg..NomineeAction na on
        ncv.session_id    = na.x_session_id   and
        ncv.committee_id  = na.x_committee_id and
        ncv.agency_id     = na.x_agency_id    and
        ncv.position_id   = na.x_position_id  and
        ncv.nominee_id    = na.x_nominee_id   and
        ncv.received_date = na.x_received_date
    inner join status..session s on
        ncv.session_id    = s.session_id
    inner join azleg..Legislator l on
        ncv.member_id     = l.x_member_id     and
        s.legislature     = l.LegislatureId
) SRC on
    SRC.agency_id     = votedetail.x_agency_id     and
    SRC.position_id   = votedetail.x_position_id   and
    SRC.nominee_id    = votedetail.x_nominee_id    and
    SRC.received_date = votedetail.x_received_date and
    SRC.session_id    = votedetail.x_session_id    and
    SRC.committee_id  = votedetail.x_committee_id  and
    SRC.member_id     = votedetail.x_member_id
where   SRC.NomineeActionId <> votedetail.NomineeActionId
   OR   SRC.LegislatorId <> votedetail.LegislatorId
   OR   SRC.Vote <> votedetail.Vote
```