# could not update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
update [RegistryCopy].[dbo].[RegFile_New]
SET r.[FileNo] = v.[Cont#Account (New ACC)]
where r.[FileNo] IN
    (
    SELECT r.[FileNo]
    FROM [RegistryCopy].[dbo].[RegFile_New] as R
    INNER JOIN
    [Registry_Malta_Recovered].[dbo].OLD_NEW_AccountsFromSap as v ON 
     r.FileNo] = v.[Acct in legacy (Old ACC)]
      where 
      r.[FileNo] = ('1000040000')
     )
```

I'm getting the error message:

> The multi-part identifier "r.FileNo" could not be bound.

Comment: we would need to see what the table definitions look like for both tables.

Comment: Is there a missing `[`? Should it read `ON [r.FileNo] =` or was this a typo on pasting the code into SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is invalid.  You're referring to aliases in the outer query that are defined in the inner query (subquery), and you're also referring to fields in the outer query for tables that are only defined in the inner query.

This is the closest approximation of your query:

```
UPDATE r
SET [FileNo] = v.[Cont#Account (New ACC)]
FROM [RegistryCopy].[dbo].[RegFile_New] AS R
INNER JOIN [Registry_Malta_Recovered].[dbo].OLD_NEW_AccountsFromSap AS v
    ON r.[FileNo] = v.[Acct in legacy (Old ACC)]
WHERE r.[FileNo] = ('1000040000')
```

Comment: Thanks guy. Although i wish to make it now for all those records not only with file no 1000040000

Comment: @user1542323 Then modify the WHERE clause appropriately?  I have no idea what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that "r" and "v" identifiers are available for the sub-query only.

Please try to use `UPDATE FROM` syntax as it was done here:
[Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

It is complaining because you are telling it to update this table/alias called `r` but this `r` is not found in the table name above.

You can rewrite the query to be this:

```
UPDATE r
SET r.[FileNo] = v.[Cont#Account (New ACC)]
FROM [RegistryCopy].[dbo].[RegFile_New] as r
INNER JOIN [Registry_Malta_Recovered].[dbo].OLD_NEW_AccountsFromSap as v
    ON r.FileNo] = v.[Acct in legacy (Old ACC)]
WHERE r.[FileNo] = ('1000040000')
```