# UPDATE query from Access to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

I have this query below from Access and I need to convert it into SQL Server:

```
UPDATE 
    (CASE_INFO 
INNER JOIN 
    CASE_PRICE ON CASE_INFO.CASE_TYPE = CASE_PRICE.CASE_TYPE) 
INNER JOIN 
     [CASECHANGE|INPUT] ON CASE_INFO.CASE_NUMBER = [CASECHANGE|INPUT].CASE_NUMBER 
SET 
   CASE_INFO.FF_REVENUE_AMT = [FF_Payment], 
   CASE_INFO.CM_REVENUE_AMT = [CM_Payment]
WHERE ((
    (CASE_INFO.SCHEDULED_DATE) Between [CASE_PRICE].[POP_START] 
    AND [CASE_PRICE].[POP_END]) 
    AND ((CASE_INFO.DISCONTINUE_30)=No));
```

Answer (score 1):

**Access:**

```
UPDATE t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.foo=t2.bar
SET t1.field = t2.otherfield
WHERE ...
```

**SQL Server:**

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.field = t2.otherfield
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.foo=t2.bar
WHERE ...
```

That should get you started.

See also [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)