# Update values in table from another table in sql unable to understand what missing

Tags: sql, sql-server

I came across situation where now 
I want to update the table but i want values which will come from 
another table.
I have written fowllowing SQL , I am sure this is very foolish question , but this is last patterm which will complete my module and need to do this ASAP

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.col1 = o.col1, 
    t.col2 = o.col2
FROM 
    other_table o 

WHERE 
    o.sql = 'cool'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you missin join

```
UPDATE t 
SET t.col1 = o.col1, 
    t.col2 = o.col2
FROM 
    other_table o 
  JOIN 
    t ON t.id = o.id
WHERE 
    o.sql = 'cool'
```

Comment: @smit you was almost there  ,
but you was just missing join there ..happy to help

Answer (score 0):

You can try it using JOINS like

```
UPDATE t
SET
    t.col1 = o.col1, 
    t.col2 = o.col2
FROM
    t
INNER JOIN
    other_table o
ON t.id = o.id
WHERE 
    o.sql = 'cool'
```