# Foreach item in a table update another table T-sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following update statement

```
Declare @customerName varchar(40)
Declare @age int

UPDATE [somedatabase].[contact] set age = @age where name = @customerName;
```

I also have a seperate table lets call cusHash with names and ages. Names are unique. I would like to read the cusHash and run my update statement for all of its values.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of going over the values of `cusHash` one by one, it would be much easier to use an update statement with a join clause:

```
UPDATE co
SET    co.age = ch.age 
FROM   [somedatabase].[contact] co
JOIN   [somedatabase].[cusHash] ch ON co.name = ch.name
```