# In a stored procedure how can you loop table A and then update table B

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Within a stored procedure I need to loop the following table:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.UsersInRoles
INNER JOIN Application_Users ON UsersInRoles.AppUserID = Application_Users.AppUserID
WHERE (UsersInRoles.ApplicationId = @ApplicationId)
AND (UsersInRoles.RoleId = @CurrentRoleId)
AND (Application_Users.LastLogin < @StartDate)
```

And for each record that is looped I need to perform this update:

```
UPDATE UsersInRoles
SET UsersInRoles.RoleId = @DenyRoleId
WHERE (UsersInRoles.ApplicationId = @ApplicationId)
AND (UsersInRoles.RoleId = @CurrentRoleId)
```

If there is a better way to perform this then I'm open to suggestions. Basically the 1st query does a filter based upon the `INNER JOIN` to determine which records need to be updated. Then those filtered records are looped and updated with a new `RoleID`.

Comment: answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server

Comment: You need to make a paradigm shift in the way you look at data. Looping is horribly inefficient. You have to change your mindset from thinking about what you need to do to a row and instead think about what you need to do to a column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update with join:

```
UPDATE UIR
SET UIR.RoleId = @DenyRoleId
FROM UsersInRoles UIR
INNER JOIN Application_Users ON UIR.AppUserID = Application_Users.AppUserID
WHERE (UIR.ApplicationId = @ApplicationId)
AND (UIR.RoleId = @CurrentRoleId)
AND (Application_Users.LastLogin < @StartDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CTE` to do the `UPDATE`:

```
;WITH ToUpdate AS (
   SELECT uir.RoleId 
   FROM dbo.UsersInRoles AS uir
   INNER JOIN Application_Users AS au 
      ON uir.AppUserID = au.AppUserID 
   WHERE (uir.ApplicationId = @ApplicationId) AND 
         (uir.RoleId = @CurrentRoleId) AND 
         (au.LastLogin < @StartDate)
)
UPDATE ToUpdate
SET RoleId = @DenyRoleId
```

So, you just type wrap the query in a `CTE` and then perform the `UPDATE` on the table returned by the `CTE`. The `RoleId` value will be propagated to the records of the actual table, `UsersInRoles`.