# Create a column with data from a join query

Tags: sql, join, group-by, sql-update, alter-table

I have two tables,

One with items:

ic_items

```
 item_id  name                description 

      1   Pepperino           Hot sauce from Argentina
      2   Vamos el Couchiero  Hot sauce from Spain
```

one with votes: (flame = 1 vote)

ic_flames

```
  flame_id  item_id

     1         1
     2         1
     3         2
```

Now I want to connect them. So something like this is joining the first table:

```
  item_id  name               description                 flame_counter

      1   Pepperino           Hot sauce from Argentina         2
      2   Vamos el Couchiero  Hot sauce from Spain             1
```

I use this query:

```
SELECT ic_items.item_id, COUNT(ic_flames.flame_id) AS flame_counter
FROM ic_flames 
JOIN ic_items ON ic_items.item_id=ic_flames.item_id
GROUP BY ic_items.item_id
```

When I fill in this query on phpmyadmin I get a table with the flame_counter, but when I go to ic_items I don't see the flame_counter.

How can I get the flame_counter into my ic_items table?

Comment: I am getting the feeling that you think running the query with the JOIN in it will make a permanent join of these tables. It wont! The joining is only done to produce the result table for that one query. Or did I misunderstand

Comment: If you want the connection to look permenant, look up VIEWS. Create a view and then use that when you want to look at this data as if it were a single table

Comment: @RiggsFolly oh damn.. I want it to be permanent yes. How do I create that view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a subquery to count the table-entries in `ic_flames` wich have the current `item_id`. Although it would be much more nicer just to implement a counter-entry into `ic_flames` instead of a new line for every vote. Here is a not tested example for your case. Hope it helps ;)

```
SELECT   ic_items.item_id, 
         ic_items.name, 
         ic_items.description,
         (
         SELECT   COUNT(*) 
         FROM     ic_flames AS sub_ic_flames
         WHERE    sub_ic_flames.item_id = ic_items.item_id
         GROUP    BY sub_ic_flames.item_id
         ) AS flame_counter
FROM     ic_items
```

//EDIT

To update flame_counter in table `ic_items` use the following query.

```
UPDATE   ic_items
SET      flame_counter = (
             SELECT   COUNT(*) 
             FROM     ic_flames AS sub_ic_flames
             WHERE    sub_ic_flames.item_id = ic_items.item_id
             GROUP    BY sub_ic_flames.item_id
         )
```

Comment: it works, but how do I get that flame_counter into the ic_items table?

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD why would you do that? with that query you get your needed data. otherwise why even having the `ic_flames` table?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but for a school project I NEED to have two tables and connect them somehow. I want that connection to be permanent.

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD i updated my answer. Hope this is what you want. but then you would need the field `flame_counter` in your `ic_items` table.

Comment: @FoxOnFireHD your welcome! would you mind accepting my answer then. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The selection here is going to do just that, select.  If you want to add them to existing items in an existing table, that is an [UPDATE statement](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp), and if you want to create a new column for those values, you need an [ALTER TABLE statement](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/tables/alter_table.php).  In your case, the alter table needs to come first, and you will need to [combine your JOIN with an UPDATE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604212/5517065), and it would look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD flame_counter int(250);

UPDATE ic_items
SET flame_counter = COUNT(flames.flame_counter)
FROM (
    SELECT ic_items.item_id, COUNT(ic_flames.flame_id) AS flame_counter
        FROM ic_flames 
    JOIN ic_items ON ic_items.item_id=ic_flames.item_id
    GROUP BY ic_items.item_id
) AS flames;
```

Comment: A view might be less of a major change

Comment: It is likely because the column that it is being grouped by has to be in the select.  I have edited the answer to (hopefully) account for the error