# Update a table based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, cfml, lucee

I am using a development environment with Lucee and SQL Server Management Studio. I have two tables:

- **Cities** - Columns: city, state, region, and zip.
- **Info** - Columns: city, state, zip

There are 80,000+ entries `Info`. I ONLY want to update the `zip` column in the `Cities` table. It is all null for each of the 22,000 entries. If there is a matching value for City and State, assign the value to `Cities` based off `Info`. I haven't figured out how to go through the whole query like that without having some kind of search value.

I've tried things like the code below. It outputs 10 from `Cities`, and the last index [9] from `Info` in 2 dumps. Why does it not display each iteration of `i`? It could be 30,000 in order to go through the whole query but still how do I update based on a value in `Info` and do it ONLY ONCE even if there are multiple matching values in `Info`. Also, if matching values do not exist in `Info`, how to not set any incorrect information?

```
<cfquery name="list" datasource="source">
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM cities
    ORDER BY CITY ASC
</cfquery>

<cfparam name="i" default="1">
<cfloop query="#list#" from="1" to="10" index="i">
  <cfoutput>#list.city[i]#</cfoutput>
  <cfoutput>#list.state[i]#</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
<cfquery name="master" datasource="source">
    SELECT TOP 10 *
    FROM WEBMASTERCOPY
    WHERE STATE = '#list.state[i]#' AND city = '#list.city[i]#'
</cfquery>
```

Comment: i read your information and write this query for you    update cities set cities.zip = info.zip from info where info.city=cities.city and info.sate=cities.state and info.zip = null

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51615103/edit) your question and add the formatted SQL query (so it's easier to read). The syntax isn't quite right. Look at the last query in the link above, it shows how the MySQL JOIN needs to be in the UPDATE (there's no FROM clause).  Something more like this `UPDATE cities c INNER JOIN info i 
ON i.state = c.state AND i.city = c.city 
SET  c.zip = i.zip
WHERE c.zip IS NULL`

Comment: @EhsanPanahi Your SQL statement was exactly what I needed!!! At first 0 lines where update and I took away The c.zip is NULL and it worked perfectly! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do 3 table JOIN in UPDATE query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query)

Comment: @EhsanPanahi - That's SQL Server syntax. MySQL uses a different syntax  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/how-to-do-3-table-join-in-update-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up being like this:

```
 update Cities
   set Cities.ZIP = Info.ZIP from Info 
   where Cities.STATE = Info.STATE
 and 
Cities.CITY = Info.CITY
```

Comment: If that syntax works - you're not using MySQL! It's valid for SQL Server, etc.. though.

Comment: @Ageax You're right, it's Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: That makes a big difference ;-) SQL syntax is often vendor specific, so be sure to tag future questions with the correct dbms to get an accurate answer.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't need ColdFusion, though you can use `cfquery`. This is MySQL that works regardless:

```
UPDATE cities t1, WEBMASTERCOPY t2
SET t1.zip = t2.zip
WHERE t1.city = t2.city AND t1.state = t2.state AND t1.zip IS NULL
```

Make a backup first =)

Comment: In 2018, shouldn't be recommending ANSI-89 JOINs anymore ;-)