# Set a row value to a variable in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, variables, syntax

I'm trying to set salesorders.pickinglocation to 448 if my salesorder is 68 and salesorderprexies are not 'SO-' OR 'QU-'. Im getting a sytax error .

```
DECLARE @SalesOrder bigint = 68       --[Identifier]  
DECLARE @PickingLocation bigint  = 448

set SalesOrders.PickingLocation = @PickingLocation

FROM SalesOrderItems
inner join salesorders on salesorderitems.salesorder = SalesOrders.SalesOrder
inner join SalesOrderPrefixes on salesorders.salesorderprefix = SalesOrderPrefixes.salesorderprefix

WHERE SalesOrders.Salesorder = @SalesOrder
AND SalesOrderPrefixes.SalesOrderPrefixId <>'SO-' AND SalesOrderPrefixes.SalesOrderPrefixId <> 'QU-'
```

Comment: Ahh yeah I didn't know about that. Is there any way i can do the OR an easier way?

Comment: To exclude both you want AND not OR & you are missing an UPDATE clause - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server

Comment: Cheers Alex K ;)

Comment: To make the where condition more readable you can try SalesOrderPrefixes.SalesOrderPrefixID NOT IN('SO-','QU-')

Comment: In general using the IN command is not very efficient, especially as the number of values increase. However compared to hard coding each condition I believe its comparable.

Comment: As @AlexK. already said: You are probably missing an `UPDATE SalesOrderItems` before your `set...`