# Update multiple rows with different values based on Ids

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called Todo. This contains a list of id's and a completedDate field which is NULL. There are some other columns but they are not used here.

I then have a query which returns the following data:
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHHBg.png)

The query is from the same table and is as follows...

```
SELECT Todo.id, MIN(CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CallStarted)
FROM Todo 
JOIN CloudCall.CloudCallHistory ON CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.ObjectId = Todo.foreignId
JOIN CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink ON CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink.CategoryCode = CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CategoryId
JOIN NotebookTypes ON NotebookTypes.NotebookTypeId = CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink.NotebookTypeId
WHERE CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CallStarted > Todo.foreignDate 
    AND Todo.completedDate IS NULL 
    AND Todo.cancelledDate IS NULL
    AND NotebookTypes.NotebookFolderId = 175
    AND CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CategoryId != 17427
GROUP BY Todo.id
```

So what I want to do is update the Todo table with the new date where the id's match. Is there anyway to do this in 1 query?

It would look something like this maybe?:

```
UPDATE Todo
SET completedDate... (SELECT...)
WHERE id = ?
```

where the select would be the query that returned the data shown in the image. Thanks

Comment: Can't you put a join between Todo in Update query with the table of the inner query?

Comment: They are both the same table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
UPDATE Todo
SET completedDate = o.otherDate
FROM Todo t
INNER JOIN (SELECT otherDate, id FROM otherTable) AS o ON t.id = o.id
```

---

*Update*

To join against the query that collects the dates:

```
UPDATE Todo
SET completedDate = o.min_date
FROM Todo t
JOIN (SELECT Todo.id, MIN(CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CallStarted) AS min_date
      FROM Todo 
      JOIN CloudCall.CloudCallHistory ON CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.ObjectId = Todo.foreignId
      JOIN CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink ON CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink.CategoryCode = CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CategoryId
      JOIN NotebookTypes ON NotebookTypes.NotebookTypeId = CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink.NotebookTypeId
      WHERE CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CallStarted > Todo.foreignDate 
        AND Todo.completedDate IS NULL 
        AND Todo.cancelledDate IS NULL
        AND NotebookTypes.NotebookFolderId = 175
        AND CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CategoryId != 17427
      GROUP BY Todo.id) AS o ON o.id = t.id
```

Comment: They are from the same table. The query is doing joins to other tables though

Comment: @WillDaniels I have updated my answer based on the query in your question

Comment: Thanks! this works, you was 1 minute quicker than the other guy so I can accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

Just use `JOIN` for this purposes:

```
UPDATE t1 
SET t1.completedDate = t2.[Column]
FROM dbo.ToDo AS t1
INNER JOIN dbo.Table2 AS t2
ON t1.CommonField = t2.[Common Field]
WHERE t1.id in (...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE Todo SET completedDate=CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CallStarted   
FROM Todo 
JOIN CloudCall.CloudCallHistory ON CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.ObjectId = Todo.foreignId
JOIN CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink ON 
CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink.CategoryCode = 
CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CategoryId 
JOIN NotebookTypes ON    
NotebookTypes.NotebookTypeId = CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink.NotebookTypeId 
WHERE    
CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CallStarted > Todo.foreignDate     AND 
Todo.completedDate IS NULL     AND Todo.cancelledDate IS NULL    AND 
NotebookTypes.NotebookFolderId = 175    AND 
CloudCall.CloudCallHistory.CategoryId != 17427
   GROUP BY Todo.id
```

Comment: Thanks im going to give this a try, 1 minute

Comment: They are from the same table, how would i match the ids?

Comment: I am a little confused here, you have a table with CompleteDate field which you said it's NULL, an you shared a set of records filled with dates, and then you say it's the same table!

Comment: yes i will update my question with the actual query so u can see

Comment: So ive added the query, it does a few joins in order to return data but the primary table is Todo

Comment: Thanks! The other guy posted his answer just before but thankyou very much anyway i appriciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Please use aliases, makes the query readable without eight pages of horizontal scrolling.

Because you're dealing with aggregate data, you'll need to use a variation on SQL Server's proprietary [`UPDATE FROM`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604212/61305) syntax:

```
;WITH aggData AS
(
    SELECT Todo.id, MinStart = MIN(ch.CallStarted)
    FROM Todo 
    INNER JOIN CloudCall.CloudCallHistory AS ch
      ON ch.ObjectId = Todo.foreignId
    INNER JOIN CloudCall.CloudCallNotebookTypeCategoryLink AS cl
      ON cl.CategoryCode = ch.CategoryId
    INNER JOIN NotebookTypes AS nt
      ON nt.NotebookTypeId = cl.NotebookTypeId
    WHERE ch.CallStarted > Todo.foreignDate 
        AND Todo.completedDate IS NULL 
        AND Todo.cancelledDate IS NULL
        AND nt.NotebookFolderId = 175
        AND ch.CategoryId <> 17427
    GROUP BY Todo.id
)
UPDATE t SET completedDate = aggData.MinStart
FROM Todo AS t
INNER JOIN aggData 
ON t.id = aggData.id;
```

You can probably simplify this so that `Todo` is only read once, but let's start with something that doesn't drastically rewrite the entire query.