# SQL Update related data when new table and data is added

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have a table `SESSIONS` and I am adding a new field `ContentId` to this table. `CONTENTs` is a new table being created in the upgrade/migration script too.
before a foreign key constraint is added, I need to set the values of `COntentId` in the `SESSIONS` table based upon the data in the newly created and populated table `CONTENTS`.

The content table has some backward compatibilty data inserted into it, such that one content is associated with one session. (Though in future, a content might have multiple sessions)

This is my query:

```
UPDATE ModuleSessions MS 
SET ModuleContentId = 
  (SELECT ID FROM ModuleContent MC WHERE 
  Name = CONCAT('Content For Session ', MS.Id))
```

It is unhappy about the `MS.Id` (Incorrect Syntax near 'MS')

Maybe there is a better way to do the subquery to get the value to update the `SESSION`?

Comment: You need to use a join in your update.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server/1604212#1604212)

Comment: Thank you for the pointers. The actual error wasn't very searchable, but using that other update table join way has solved the issue.