# Copy data from one row to another in SQL Server in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has two variations of data:

Table `MYDATA`

```
Address           StreetNumber       Provider
----------------------------------------------
123 Main Street   1                  VersionA
123 Main Street   NULL               VersionB
```

I would like to update Version A's StreetNumber into Version B.

There will be thousands of records and the match will be on the Address column

I thought to use:

```
update MYDATA
set StreetNumber = (select top 1 streetnumber
                    from MYDATA Goo 
                    where Goo.Address = Address and Provider = 'VersionA')
where Provider = 'VersionB'
```

But it seems the nesting is not looking at the row to be updated...rather its picking one record and updating all records with the same streetnumber?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Comment: Create a SELECT statement that returns both the current value and the value you want returned and then convert that to an UPDATE statement.  I found that is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: @PM77-1 While the similarties are great, my question deals with the same one table whereas the other "seemingly duplicate question" deals with multiple tables.  I don't see this as a duplicate.  If that is not clear feel free to edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *should* work:

```
UPDATE MDb
SET StreetNumber = MDa.StreetNumber
FROM MYDATA MDb
     JOIN MYDATA MDa ON MDb.[Address] = MDa.[Address]
WHERE MDb.Provider = 'VersionB'
  AND MDa.Provider = 'VersionA'; --You can move this clause to the ON if you prefer
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Came across similar issue. Copying data from one row to another under the same column and inside the same table. Maybe this will help.

```
   UPDATE MyData 
   SET StreetNumber = newdata.StreetNumber

   FROM (
   SELECT Password FROM [MyDB].[dbo].[MyData]
   WHERE Provider = VersionA
   )newdata

   WHERE Provider = VersionB
```