# How to update table multiple times based on another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a table multiple times based on data from another table.
Below is the table design I have at the moment:

```
Table A                          Table B
--------------------             --------------------
Goods    QTY    Type             Goods    QTY    Type
Wood      0       R1             Wood       1      R1
Wood     10       R2             Wood       4      R1
Glass    10       R1             Wood       5      R1
Glass     0       R2             Glass      5      R2
                                 Glass      4      R2
```

I would like to do the **addition** on **QTY** in Table A based on **QTY** from Table B, if possible in one update statement.

Expected output is something like this:

```
Table A
--------------------
Goods    QTY    Type
Wood     10       R1 ---> Previous value: 0
Wood     10       R2
Glass    10       R1
Glass     9       R2 ---> Previous value: 0
```

I already tried the below update statement to no avail:

```
UPDATE Table A
SET A.QTY = A.QTY + B.QTY
FROM Table A as A JOIN Table B as B ON A.Goods = B.Goods AND A.Type = B.Type
```

However, the above query statement is only updating the first distinct value on Table B. It only update the `QTY` of `Wood` to `1`, and `QTY` of `Glass` to `5`.

Comment: Hint, you need to do a GROUP BY and SUM() on table B

Comment: You could use a common table expression. This solution is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604212/245915.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an inline subquery, like:

```
UPDATE TableA A
SET A.QTY = A.QTY + (
   SELECT SUM(B.QTY) FROM TableB B WHERE A.Goods = B.Goods AND A.Type = B.Type
)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, aggregate `Table B` by summing the `Qty` field for each unique combination of `Goods` & `Type` using a combination of the `sum` function and `group by` clause.

```
select t.goods, t.type, sum(t.qty) as tqty
from [table b] t
group by t.goods, t.type
```

Then join this subquery to `Table A`:

```
update [table a] a join
(
    select t.goods, t.type, sum(t.qty) as tqty
    from [table b] t
    group by t.goods, t.type
) b 
on a.goods = b.goods and a.type = b.type
set a.qty = a.qty + b.tqty
```