# How to update a column with data from another column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I have a SQL Server table with multiple columns 2 of which are `Kwd` and `UserName`. I am trying to update all values in column `UserName` with values from column `Kwd`. Both columns are of type `nvarchar`.

I am using the below query.

```
UPDATE test_table1 
SET UserName = Kwd
```

I have also tried

```
SET a.UserName = B.Kwd 
FROM test_table1 a 
INNER JOIN test_table1 b ON a.PelID = b.PelID
```

However it updates all column with value "sa", what could be wrong?

Update 1:

I have tried testing an easier approach to see what will happen When I run the query:

```
UPDATE test_table1 
SET UserName = 'test'
```

it still updates all rows with value `sa`

Comment: Is there any trigger on this table?

Comment: @Suraj_Kumar Yes, you are right. there was a trigger in place. After deleting the trigger it updated immediately. However now the software that is based on this DB fails to load. pfffff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this as shown below.

```
UPDATE a 
    SET a.UserName = b.Kwd
    FROM test_table1 a INNER JOIN test_table1 b ON a.Id= b.Id
```

You can also try the following query.

```
update test_table1 
   set test_table1.UserName = B.Kwd
  from test_table1 B
```

You can follow the link [Inner join update in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Here is an example with sample data.

```
create table test_table1 (PelID int, Kwd varchar(10), UserName varchar(10))
insert into test_table1 Values (1, 'A', 'B'), (2, 'K', 'P'), (3, 'N', 'S'), (4, 'G', 'H'), (5, 'T', 'F')

Select * from test_table1

UPDATE a 
    SET a.UserName = b.Kwd
    FROM test_table1 a INNER JOIN test_table1 b ON a.PelID = b.PelID

Select * from test_table1

update test_table1 
   set test_table1.UserName = B.Kwd
  from test_table1 B

Select * from test_table1
```

This output can be checked on the [link](https://rextester.com/WPRV41686)

Comment: Both columns are part from the same table. do i need to use INNER JOIN for updating columns within the same table?

Comment: @Meni You can do it by either join or without join also. I have updated my answer, please check.

Comment: this is driving me crazy. i have tried both your methods and they produce the same results. the command passes through without errors. However all rows in column UserName becomes `sa`

Comment: Something is terribly wrong. i get the same result even if i try: `UPDATE test_table1 UserName = 'test' `

Comment: Ya, you need to check if your query is producing the wrong result, however the way is correct.

Comment: There was a trigger that was producing the undersired results. after deleting the trigger the table updated correctly. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE test_table1 SET UserName = test_table1.Kwd WHERE test_table1.id=some_id
```

Enter record id

Comment: I would like to update all rows in the table. i have tried specifying an id in order to update a specific ro and it produces the same result.