# how to update data from two tables if the value is the same

Tags: sql-server, select

I have two tables in both tables have a BSONUM column, I need to update table1 column REIS if in both tables BSONUM = BSONUM

made a query in SQL Server but does not work

[image]

Comment: You should add sample data and desired result

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update a table using JOIN in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do  `join` & always define table alias:

```
update t
     set t.reis_t = s.reis
from ticket t inner join
     segements s
     on s.bsonum = t.bsonum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Apperently there is ambiguity in the column name BSONUM
Have you tried doing `WHERE FirstTable.BSONUM = SecondTable.BSONUM`

If you have two columns with the same name from two tables the engine has issue understanding which one you are referring to. Thus, you need to specify table name as well.