# New to UPDATE with INNER JOIN

Tags: sql-update, inner-join

I'm new to updating records using an INNER JOIN.

I tried this (based on code on [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server#))

```
UPDATE
    ticket_sold
SET
    ticket_sold_refund = 1
FROM
    ticket
INNER JOIN
    ticket_sold ON ticket_sold_ticket_no = ticket_id
WHERE 
    ticket_multi = 14200
AND 
    ticket_sold_sale_no = 21587
```

It looks ok to mee but mySql says the error is on ticket_sold_refund = 1

Could someone point out my probably obvious error please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rearranging it a few times I solved it:

```
UPDATE
    ticket_sold
INNER JOIN
    ticket ON ticket_sold_ticket_no = ticket_id
SET
    ticket_sold_refund = 1
WHERE 
    ticket_multi = 14200
AND 
    ticket_sold_sale_no = 21587
```