# What are the scoping rules for UPDATE when mixed with a JOIN?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, sql-update

Whenever I read how to use a `JOIN` to `UPDATE` a table, the usage of aliases always throws me off just slightly. For example, take this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1293350/10319707)

```
UPDATE ud
SET assid = s.assid
FROM ud u
JOIN sale s ON u.id=s.id
```

It's clear to me that `assid` comes from the `ud` table on the line 1. What isn't clear to me is why `ud` needed to be aliased on lines 3 and 4. This isn't an isolated incident. For example, another answer on that same page is

```
update u
set u.assid = s.assid
from ud u
    inner join sale s on
        u.id = s.udid
```

which uses the alias `u` in a great many places.

This gives me my question: What exactly are the rules for what you do/don't need to alias when trying to use a `JOIN` to `UPDATE`? Directly quoting from any relevant docs would be appreciated, but not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql) calls this out specifically:

> `FROM <table_source>`
>
> ... *snip* ...
>
> If the object being updated is the same as the object in the `FROM` clause and there is only one reference to the object in the `FROM` clause, an object alias may or may not be specified. If the object being updated appears more than one time in the `FROM` clause, one, and only one, reference to the object must not specify a table alias. All other references to the object in the `FROM` clause must include an object alias.

You do not *have* to specify an alias for any table. If you do not then the table can obviously only be specified once.

But if you do give an alias then it depends: if the table exists in the query once then either with or without an alias is OK. Otherwise you *must* use the alias.

**To be honest,** [as @AaronBertrand says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72070388/14868997), do yourself and everyone a favour and *always* use an alias on each table, and specify that alias in the `UPDATE alias SET` part.

Equally you should always use table aliases for each column reference in the joins or expressions. This is the same as you should do in any `SELECT`.

However, I **don't** think it's necessary to use it on the left-hand-side columns being assigned to, as these can only ever be from a single table/view/alias: the one directly after the keyword `UPDATE`, so adding table aliases is just verbiage.
<sub>In SQL dialects such as MySQL which do allow this then you should specify the table alias even on the left-hand-side.</sub>

> `column_name`
>
> Is a column that contains the data to be changed. column_name must exist in table_or view_name.

So a recommended statement would look like this:

```sql
UPDATE u     -- use the alias mentioned below
SET
  assid = s.assid    -- lh-side doesn't need alias, right-side does
FROM ud u    -- alias all tables
JOIN sale s ON u.id = s.id    -- add table aliases to all columns in joins
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that none of this is mysterious if you use a CTE instead of UPDATE ... FROM, eg start with a SELECT that returns the rows you want to update

```
  select u.id, u.assid, s.assid new_assid 
  FROM ud u
  JOIN sale s ON u.id=s.id
```

.  Examine and validate the data, then wrap it in a CTE and UPDATE it

```
with q as
(
  select u.id, u.assid, s.assid new_assid 
  FROM ud u
  JOIN sale s ON u.id=s.id
)
update q set assid = new_assid
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you don't *need* to use an alias prefix on a column reference:

- in the left-hand side of `SET` since, logically, that column can't possibly come from any other table
- if there are no column name conflicts that need disambiguation (and you know for sure you will never add columns to any of the involved tables that *could* become a conflict)

IMHO you shouldn't worry about any "rules" about when you can get away with *not* prefixing, and just always reference the alias a column belongs to. Why not just be clear and explicit always?

If you're looking for "official" rules, I think you'll be out of luck. Nothing about this could be found in [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql), though the first example has this, which is a little overboard IMHO (and doesn't use aliases):

```
UPDATE dbo.Table2   
SET dbo.Table2.ColB = dbo.Table2.ColB + dbo.Table1.ColB  
FROM dbo.Table2   
    INNER JOIN dbo.Table1   
    ON (dbo.Table2.ColA = dbo.Table1.ColA);
```

On this site, many long-standing canonical examples are fully explicit on all column references, e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1604212/61305).

Comment: It's not just over the top, it's [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15). And the docs do specify the rules

Comment: @Charlieface I guess I meant specifically about the two bullet points I mentioned: on the left-hand side of `SET` and when a column name can only exist in one of the tables (for now). I also don't take much meaning from `must not specify a table alias`.

Comment: Probably should be "may" rather than "must". It's coming from the other perspective: if you have *not* used the alias in the `UPDATE ... SET` and there are multiple references then exactly one reference may have no alias. I agree it's rather unclear, and could do with cleaning up and clarifying, as could many of the examples. I also agree that you should *always* specify the alias to the left of `SET`. But I don't think it's necessary on each column reference being assigned to (as opposed to part of the expression to assign) as only one table/view can ever be updated in a single `UPDATE`