# Calculate Hourly Energy Consumption

Tags: sql-server

I have a Table 'Meter1' in my MSSQL database DB_TEST. Table structure is like this,

| MeterID | Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 11:00:00.000 | 1800 |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 12:00:00.000 | 1805 |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 13:00:00.000 | 1820 |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 14:00:00.000 | 1860 |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 15:00:00.000 | 1875 |

I need to calculate the hourly consumption by substracting the current value - previous value.

I have achieved this by using LAG function,

```
SELECT [MeterID]
      ,[Timestamp]
      ,[Value]
,VALUE -  LAG (VALUE) 
      OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP)  AS Consumption
  FROM [DB_TEST].[dbo].[Meter1]
```

& the results like this

| MeterID | Timestamp | Value | Consumption |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 11:00:00.000 | 1800 | NULL |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 12:00:00.000 | 1805 | 5 |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 13:00:00.000 | 1820 | 15 |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 14:00:00.000 | 1860 | 40 |
| 7 | 2022-09-16 15:00:00.000 | 1875 | 15 |

But how can I update or Insert the same results to my existing table with another column "Consumption".

Comment: alter the table then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1604091/update-a-table-using-join-in-sql-server

Comment: Why do you need write dynamic values into table? They go stale quickly. You can always consume results of your query.

Comment: is there any primary key or unique key? You need that to find the row for update. Also you can create a view instead of persist value in table.